# Maybe.. compatibility problems between 2.7 and 3.4?

Tags: python

I got a problem.

My code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

And it's weird. I got an error message.

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "E:/빅데이터 캠퍼스/untitled1/floating point_new.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/빅데이터 캠퍼스/untitled1/floating point_new.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 40, in <module>
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 72, in <module>
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2972, in <module>
import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx  # noqa
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 34, in <module>
import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\converter.py", line 7, in <module>
import matplotlib.units as units
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 720
except Exception, msg:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why. Help me~~

edit

And I have already installed matplotlib in python 2.7 and 3.4 like below picture.

[image]

Comment: Look at the last two lines: `File "C:\Python34\lib...`, `File "C:\Python27\...`. Doesn't look good: you're supposed to have 34 or 27 all around. All your modules have to be installed for the specific python version you're using. Matplotlib (used by pandas) seems to be off.

Comment: off?? How can I solve this problem??

Comment: "it is off" as in "something's wrong about it". I mean that your python 3 pandas installation is trying to use a python 2 matplotlib. That doesn't sound right at all. You could either try removing and reinstalling pandas, or getting familiar with virtualenvs to make sure your python versions don't mingle.

Comment: Thanks~~ You are great guy~~

Comment: No worries:) I hope it'll work out either way.